# Register object with Autofac so it acts like a controller

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a class that I'm calling `EndPointConfigurator` and I would like to inject some things, specifically a Unit of Work, into it and use it in that class.

```
 public class EndPointConfigurator
 {
     private static UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
     public EndPointConfigurator(IUnitOfWork uow)
     {
         _unitOfWork = (UnitOfWork)uow;
     }              

     //use unit of work
 }
```

I register my controllers as such:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(getExecutingAssembly)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

I was wondering what is the best way to register this class so that it can get something injected into it like controllers do. Controllers don't have interfaces and I don't want or need an interface for this class because I won't be needing to inject it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the type as itself :

```
builder.RegisterType<EndPointConfigurator>().As<EndpointConfigurator>();
```

or

```
builder.RegisterType<EndPointConfigurator>().AsSelf();
```

or if you don't specify any service, *Autofac* will automatically register as itself

```
builder.RegisterType<EndPointConfigurator>();
```

I prefer the first solution, this way we explicity tell the container what we want to do.